# Opa : give a name to a binary resource

Tags: download, binary, opa

I'm trying to download a file from an opa database. I've used the following code :

```
case {path:[], query:[("download", filename)], ...} : Resource.binary(/myDatabase[filename], "application/txt")
```

It's working fine, but the file I download is always named "download.txt". How can I change this name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case {path:[], query:[("download", filename)], ...} : Resource.binary(/myDatabase[filename], "application/txt") |> Resource.add_header(_, {content_disposition={attachment=filename}})
```